# Powershell invoke-command $input

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I have a trouble.. Can someone help me?
Here is my Code :

```
$A = '123'
$servers = 'computer1'
$Properties = [ordered]@{A = $A
                          servers = $servers     
                        }

$MyObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties

$MyObjec
...

$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName Machine -UseSSL -InDisconnectedSession -ScriptBlock {
$MyObject.A
$MyObject.servers
$env:computername
}`
–InputObject $MyObjec -port 5986 -ConfigurationName myEndpoint -SessionOption @{OutputBufferingMode="Drop"} -Credential $credential | Receive-PSSession

$result
```

Question:
Why the `$result` doesn't show anything about `$MyObject`?

It only show `$MyObjec` (not in the invoke-command) and `$env:computername` (in the invoke-command)

How can I fix it?

P.S this is really what I want to make,
I want to get into multiple machine which in 6 different AD in the same time, but they should use different username,
and I need $A in the remote machine to deal another thing.

```
$A = '123'
    $servers = 'computer1'
    $Properties = [ordered]@{A = $A
                              servers = $servers     
                            }

    $MyObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties

    $MyObjec
    ...

#Add
$servers@{'Machine1','Machine2','Machine3'}

Foreach ($servers in $servers) {

Star-Job {

$username = $servers+'account'

$password = $password

$credential = ....($username,$password)

    $result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -UseSSL -InDisconnectedSession -ScriptBlock {
    $MyObject.A
    $MyObject.servers
    $env:computername
    }`
    –InputObject $MyObjec -port 5986 -ConfigurationName myEndpoint -SessionOption @{OutputBufferingMode="Drop"} -Credential $credential | Receive-PSSession

    $result
}
```

}

I will try -Argument-List and param{}
Beacase I try Start-Job with -Argument-List and $Using, there have an error.
Thank u for your reply!

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want to achieve with your script. But I would always use `$MyObject` with a t at the end.

Comment: Thank you,In fact,my achievement is to run the invoke-command parallel in the same time.I edit my code clean!

Comment: today I test that, It can work! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the part within `-Scriptblock { ... }` gets executed on the remote system and has therefore no access to the variables on the local system (different scope).

You can change that by passing the variables to the remote system using the `-Argument-List` parameter like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Machine -ArgumentList $MyObject -ScriptBlock { 
    param($MyObject)

    $MyObject.A
}
```

Or use `$using:` to get access to the locally defined variables like that:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Machine -ScriptBlock { 

    $using:MyObject.A
}
```